# How to build a recursive type remapper in TypeScript that remaps optional keys differently

Tags: typescript

I have a collection of utility functions that validates a variable's type. For
example `string()`, `non_empty_string()`, `array()`, `non_null_object()` and so
on. They are all predicate functions and returns a `boolean` value (not
following the `is<TypeName>()` naming convention though!). All the utility
functions belongs to an object of type `Utility`.

```
interface Utility {
  string: (v: unknown) => v is string;
  number: ...;
  natural_number: ...;
  array: ...;
  non_empty_array: ...;
  ...
  ...
}

type UtilityTypes = keyof Utility;
```

But now I want to make a validator function that validates object with those
given utility methods. So if I have a user object of the `User` type,

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  isStudent?: boolean;
  address: {
    city: string;
    state: string;
    phone?: string;
  }
}
```

then I want use an schema like the following:

```
type UserValidatorSchema = {
  readonly name: UtilityTypes;
  readonly age: UtilityTypes;
  readonly "isStudent?": UtilityTypes;
  readonly address: {
    readonly city: UtilityTypes;
    readonly state: UtilityTypes;
    readonly "phone?": UtilityTypes;
  }
}

const userSchema: UserValidatorSchema = {
  name: "non_empty_string",
  age: "natural_number",
  "isStudent?": "boolean";
  address: {
    city: "non_empty_string";
    state: "non_empty_string";
    "phone?": "non_empty_string";
  }
}
```

All the optional properties should end with a "?" character so that my validator
function can recognize it as an optional property.

Now my question is is there any way I can generate the `UserValidatorSchema`
automatically from the given `User` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution.

Here's the `ValidatorSchema` remapper:

```
type ValidatorSchema<Type extends object> = {
  +readonly [key in keyof Type as ModifyOptionalKey<Type, key>]-?: NonNullable<
    Type[key]
  > extends object
    ? ValidatorSchema<NonNullable<Type[key]>>
    : UtilityTypes;
};

type ModifyOptionalKey<
  Type,
  Key extends keyof Type
> = undefined extends Type[Key] ? `${Key & string}?` : Key;

//---------------- Usages ---------------
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  isGoldUser?: boolean; 
}

type UserSchema = ValidatorSchema<User>;
/*
  UserSchema = {
    readonly name: UtilityTypes;
    readonly age: UtilityTypes;
    readonly "isGoldUser?": UtilityTypes
  } 
*/
```

##### Explanation

---

###### `ModifyOptionalKey`

This key remapper remaps any optional field's name into `<fieldName>?` (just
adds a "?" character at the end). It usages a conditional type and template
literal to accomplish this.

```
interface User {
  name?: string;
}
```

Here the typeof the name field is actually `string | undefined` because as the
name field is optional it may not be present in the object so its default value
is undefined. So with this

> `` undefined extends Type[Key] ? `${Key & string}?` : Key; ``

statement we can determine whether a property is optional. If it's optional then
we convert it to `<property>?` with `` `${Key & string}?` `` otherwise we just
return the original `Key`(property).

###### `ValidatorSchema`

> `+readonly [key in keyof Type as ModifyOptionalKey<Type, key>]-?`

1. `+readonly` makes every property `readonly`
2. `[key in keyof Type as ModifyOptionalKey<Type, key>]` remaps the optional
   keys
3. `-?` removes the optional modifier from any property thus making it required.

Now as our key reammping is done we need to take care of the property type. A
property of our validator schema can either be of `UtilityTypes` or another
`ValidatorSchema`. So if a property is an `object` then it should also
be a `ValidatorSchema`.

We can simply achieve this with a conditional type.

> `Type[key] extends object ? ValidatorSchema<Type[key]> : UtilityTypes;`

If `Type[key]` refers to an object then generate its `ValidatorSchema` with
a recursive call : `ValidatorSchema<Type[key]>` otherwise if it's a primitive
type then return `UtilityTypes`.

But there is a problem here! What would happen if one of our sub-schema is
optional? For example the `address` field in the following `User` type!

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  address?: {
      city: string;
      state: string;
  }
}
```

Here the `address` field represents a sub-schema inside the
`ValidatorSchema<User>` schema and its type
is: `{city: string; state: string} | undefined`.

```
type ReturnType = User["address"] extends object
  ? ValidatorSchema<User["address"]>
  : UtilityTypes

// ReturnType = UtilityTypes
```

We get `UtilityTypes` because `undefined extends object` returns false. To
remove the `undefined` from `User["address"]`'s type we'll use a `UtilityType`
called `NonNullable`

**Note:** Typescript's own utility types e.g., `Required`, `Record`, `Pick` etc.
Not refering to our utility types e.g., `string()`, `non_null_object()` etc.
See in the question above.

The `NonNullable<T>` removes `undefined` and `null` from any union type.
For Example

```
type nullableType = undefined | null | string;

type nonNullableType = NonNullable<nullableType>;
// nonNullableType = string
```

So `NonNullable<User["address"]>` would give use the type
`{city: string; state: string}`.

Now if we use following statement with `NonNullable` everything works as
expected.

```
NonNullable<Type[key]> extends object
    ? ValidatorSchema<NonNullable<Type[key]>>
    : UtilityTypes;
```

I learned all of this from the "TypeScript Handbook".